# Change network chart dynamically with d3plus.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3plus

I'm working now on visualization of some networks using [D3plus](http://d3plus.org/) library. What I want to do is to show different networks depending on the key of the object, e.g. year. There is a [working example](http://d3plus.org/examples/advanced/10754920/) with *tree_map* chart. But I couldn't implement the same for *network*.

**Here is my code:**

```html
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="http://www.d3plus.org/js/d3.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.d3plus.org/js/d3plus.js"></script>

<div id="viz"></div>

<script>
  var sample_data = [
    {"name": "point1", "year": 1994},
    {"name": "point2", "year": 1994},
    {"name": "point3", "year": 1994},
    {"name": "point4", "year": 1994},
    {"name": "point5", "year": 1994},
    {"name": "point6", "year": 1994},
    {"name": "point7", "year": 1994},
    {"name": "point8", "year": 1994},
    {"name": "point9", "year": 1994},
    {"name": "point10", "year": 1994},
    {"name": "point11", "year": 1994},
    {"name": "point12", "year": 1995}
  ]

  var positions = [
    {"name": "point1", "x": 3, "y": 7},
    {"name": "point2", "x": 2, "y": 6},
    {"name": "point3", "x": 4, "y": 6},
    {"name": "point4", "x": 1, "y": 5.5},
    {"name": "point5", "x": 5, "y": 5.5},
    {"name": "point6", "x": 2, "y": 4},
    {"name": "point7", "x": 4, "y": 4},
    {"name": "point8", "x": 1, "y": 3},
    {"name": "point9", "x": 5, "y": 3},
    {"name": "point10", "x": 2, "y": 1.5},
    {"name": "point11", "x": 4, "y": 1.5},
    {"name": "point12", "x": 2, "y": 7}
  ]

  var connections = []

  var visualization = d3plus.viz()
    .container("#viz")
    .type("network")
    .data(sample_data)   
    .nodes(positions)
    .edges(connections)
    .id("name")
    .time({"value": "year", "solo": 1994})
    .draw()

</script>
```

**I need to show different nodes on click at the timeline, so that by choosing 1995 only "point12" node should be shown.**

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/sabujiyini/2/edit)

**NOTE:** what I have found also is [an opened issue](https://github.com/alexandersimoes/d3plus/issues/64), but maybe this functionality was already implemented since that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to listen to the event triggered by the timeline and run custom code when the year range changes. Here is a re-interpretation of something in [a post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3plus/vuciSE5XJ3k) from the Google Group for D3plus:

```
visualization.time({"solo": {
    "callback": function(timeline_range) {

        // update the nodes/edges
        visualization.nodes(new_nodes).edges(new_edges).draw();

    }
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have spent some time solving this problem and decided to combine d3plus and d3 together instead of using just d3plus. Maybe there is not an elegant solution and it can be solved simpler, but for me it works.

So here is full code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="http://www.d3plus.org/js/d3.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.d3plus.org/js/d3plus.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
  #viz {
    height: 600px;
  }
  #network-timeline {
    height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .time-tick {
    background-color: #6f6d6d;
    outline: 0;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #FFF;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    height: 28px;
    margin: 0 0 15px 5px;
    padding: 0 0.8rem;
    border-radius: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18), 0 4px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18), 0 4px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18), 0 4px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  }
  .time-tick:hover {
    background-color: #9e9e9e;
  }
  .time-tick-selected {
    background-color: #9e9e9e; 
  }
</style>

<div class="network">
  <div id="viz"></div>
  <div id="network-timeline"></div>
</div>

<script>
  var initial_data = [
    {"name": "point1", "year": 1994, "x": 3, "y": 7},
    {"name": "point2", "year": 1994, "x": 2, "y": 6},
    {"name": "point3", "year": 1994, "x": 4, "y": 6},
    {"name": "point4", "year": 1994, "x": 1, "y": 5.5},
    {"name": "point5", "year": 1994, "x": 5, "y": 5.5},
    {"name": "point6", "year": 1994, "x": 2, "y": 4},
    {"name": "point7", "year": 1994, "x": 4, "y": 4},
    {"name": "point8", "year": 1994, "x": 1, "y": 3},
    {"name": "point9", "year": 1994, "x": 5, "y": 3},
    {"name": "point10", "year": 1994, "x": 2, "y": 1.5},
    {"name": "point11", "year": 1994, "x": 4, "y": 1.5},
    {"name": "point1", "year": 1995, "x": 3, "y": 7},
    {"name": "point2", "year": 1995, "x": 2, "y": 6},
    {"name": "point3", "year": 1995, "x": 4, "y": 6},
    {"name": "point4", "year": 1995, "x": 1, "y": 5.5},
    {"name": "point5", "year": 1995, "x": 5, "y": 5.5},
    {"name": "point6", "year": 1995, "x": 4, "y": 4.5},
    {"name": "point7", "year": 1995, "x": 1, "y": 3.5},
    {"name": "point8", "year": 1995, "x": 2, "y": 3.5},
    {"name": "point9", "year": 1995, "x": 1.5, "y": 1},
    {"name": "point10", "year": 1995, "x": 4, "y": 1.5},
    {"name": "point11", "year": 1995, "x": 5, "y": 2},
  ]

  var connections = []

  var filterData = function(data, key) {
    return data.filter(function(obj){
      if (!obj.hasOwnProperty("year")) {
        console.error("Check input data. Every object should contain 'year' property.")
      }
      return obj.year == key
    });
  }

  var timeButtonClickHandler = function() {
    selectNetwork(this);
    selectTimeButton(this);
  }

  var selectNetwork = function(el) {
    var slice = filterData(slices, el.value)[0].nodes;
    drawNetwork(slice);
  }

  var drawNetwork = function(data) {
    visualization.data(data)   
                 .nodes(data)
                 .edges(connections)
                 .id("name")
                 .draw();
  }

  var selectTimeButton = function(el) {
    var button = document.querySelector(".time-tick-selected")
    if (button){
      button.className = "time-tick"
    }
    el.className = "time-tick time-tick-selected"
  }

  var visualization = d3plus.viz()
    .container("#viz")
    .type("network");

  // Create slices of nodes by key "year" according to timeline
  var timeSteps = d3plus.util.uniques(initial_data, function(d){return d.year}).sort();
  var slices = [];
  timeSteps.forEach(function(step){
    slices.push({
      "year": step,
      "nodes": filterData(initial_data, step)
    });
  });

  // Create timeline buttons
  d3.select("#network-timeline")
    .selectAll("input")
    .data(timeSteps)
    .enter()
    .append("input")
    .attr("type","button")
    .attr("class","time-tick")
    .attr("value", function (d){return d})
    .on("click", timeButtonClickHandler);

  // Draw initial network
  if (timeSteps.length > 0) {
    var button = document.querySelector("input[value='" + timeSteps[0] + "']");
    if (button){button.click()}
  }
  else {
    console.error("Check input data. Every object should contain 'year' property.")
  } 
</script>
```

[JSbin example](http://jsbin.com/kalonoqume/1/)